# Php sessions in different browsers

Tags: php, session, browser

If I log in to a website with the same user name and password in different browsers then close one of the windows, will the session still exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to concreticise preceeding answers. The browsers don't have any kind of connections between them - they are standalone applications. If browser starts a seesion, it belongs to it until it is unset e.g. 
    B1 => Sess 1
    B2 => Sess 2
And neither of them is accessible somewhere else than it the browser that created it.
More information about PHP sessions can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php. You can find there "A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL." and that is the answer to your question :-D

Answer (score 5):

- Browser 1 starts session 1, when
  closing browser 1 this will close
  session 1
- Browser 2 starts session 2, when
  closing browser 2 this will close
  session 2

Browser 1 can not end session 2, nor can browser 2 end session 1

Answer (score 1):

The Session in the still opened Browser will still exist, yes (Exept the website has a mechanism to avoid double sessions, or kills all sessions form a User at once)

Comment: ever thought about accepting some answers on your questions? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The session is local to the browser.  Two browsers = two sessions.  That is, unless you have some javascript (window.close) forcing the logout.